# Can't set custom CSS in WordPress theme

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using the Twenty Fourteen theme in my WordPress web site. On [one of the pages](http://glass.glaciallakesmn.com/primerequipment/) I want to add images on the left side of the content area (menu sidebar is to the left of that) such that the text wraps around the image.

I have added two images (near the third and fourth H4 tags, if you take a look at the page) and both of the images are being forced behind the left sidebar due to the theme's -168px margin-left setting on the image's parent figure element.

On the page, if you use an Element Inspector/FireBug/whatever, you'll see the images nested in figure elements in the code and that it's way off to the left behind the sidebar. In the Rules viewer, it's showing a `margin-left: -168px` on classes `".full-width .site-content .wp-caption.alignleft"`

I added my own class to the images to try to offset the margin by using `margin-right: 168px`, but it's not having an effect, presumably because the -168 left margin setting is on an element that is a parent of the image.

I don't want to select all figure elements to offset that -168px - I may want that for other figures - I don't know. WP adds an ID to each image, but I don't want to have to select each and every image ID (unless that's the only way), so how do I handle this?

Thanks for anyone's help.

[image: Note the partial view of the image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more fiddling around looking at the CSS and trying some settings I realized that I kind of answered my own question. I said that the figure element that the image is in has a setting of `margin-left: -186px;`. All I had to do was add my own CSS: `figure { margin-left: 0px; }`. Why I didn't see that sooner, I don't know...

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `.alignleft` class from the `figure`'s html.

This will remove the margin.

To get the text to flow around the figure you need to give it a property of `float: left` and add some right and left margin to make it look a bit nicer.

html for the figure (your image) should read:

```
<figure id="attachment_10" style="width: 88px; float: left; margin: 0 20px 0 10px;" class="wp-caption">
```

I'd say you should look at styling elements in css stylesheets as opposed to defining your styles in html.

A book for you would be:

HTML & CSS: Design and Build Web Sites
By Jon Duckett

Its what I used when I first started CSS. Its got all you'll most likely need for a while and very beginner friendly...

Comment: Thanks, Joe, but I'm just adding the image using the Visual editor. The only CSS I've added is .primerPics in the image editor to try to force positioning of the image, but that didn't work. WordPress and/or the theme is adding an anchor around the img tag, and further, the figure tag isn't even visible in the Text mode of the page editor - it must be added by the theme template when the page is rendered. So I don't have access to the figure tag.